# Is there a way to insert multiple elements to different locations in a ndarray all at once?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm using numpy's ndarray, and I'm wondering is there a way that allows me to insert multiple elements to different locations all at once?

For example, I have an image, and I want to pad the image with 0s. This is what I currently have:

```
def zero_padding(self):
        padded = self.copy()
        padded.img = np.insert(self.img, 0, 0, axis = 0)
        padded.img = np.insert(padded.img, padded.img.shape[0], 0, axis = 0)
        padded.img = np.insert(padded.img, 0, 0, axis = 1)
        padded.img = np.insert(padded.img, padded.img.shape[1], 0, axis = 1)
        return padded
```

where `padded` is an instance of the image.

Comment: np.insert is the most general tool.  But it is python, so can read it gain ideas that apply specifically to your case.  Basically it creates a `zeros` array of the right size and copies values to it.,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can use the `fancy indexing` techinque of `NumPy` as follows:

```
import numpy as np


if __name__=='__main__':
    A = np.zeros((5, 5))
    A[[1, 2], [0, 3]] = 1
    print(A)
```

**Output:**

```
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

Cheers

Comment: Thank you very much!